# How to Accept All Changes In Selection?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to accept all changes in a selection, in Word 2013.

I used the macro recorder and it generated the following code (it can also be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.revisions.acceptall)

```
Selection.Range.Revisions.AcceptAll
```

However, it will not work unless I physically select each letter

[image]
[image]

But if I use the built in buttons in the 'Changes' group within the 'Review' tab, I don't have to physically select the entire letter.  I just need to select any part of the change and it will accept the change.

[image]
[image]

Why does the macro version not perform like the UI option?

Comment: The code works provided you select the *entire* range of the revisions concerned.

Comment: I figured that but that still doesn't explain why the UI will work with partial range but the macro will only work with full range when the macro recorder and the UI yield the identical code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd behavior. The UI must be doing something like the below, but whoever built the macro recorder missed it.

```
Public Sub AcceptSelection()
    
    Dim rev As Revision
    
    For Each rev In Selection.Range.Revisions
        rev.Accept
    Next rev
    
End Sub
```

That code will accept any revisions in the selection, even partial ones.

Comment: That works!  Thank you!  I ran the macro recorder and it gave me the code above.  But when I ran the macro, it wasn't performing like the UI from which I recorded (partial vs full).  So I went to the Microsoft website to check to see if I missed anything and it listed the same code that I recorded so I was completely stumped.